# default command with Python argparse

Tags: python, argparse

[As the official document of argparse says](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html),

> One particularly effective way of handling sub-commands is to combine the use of the add_subparsers() method with calls to set_defaults()

I'd like to implement some commands such as foo and bar, where foo is the **default command**.  What's the simplest way?  These commands have shared and non-shared arguments and options.  Default foo command has only options, no arguments.

Required command line and output:

```
$ python m.py
foo
$ python m.py -a
foo(a)
$ python m.py foo
foo
$ python m.py foo -a
foo(a)
$ python m.py bar
bar
$ python m.py bar -b
bar(b)
```

Thanks in advance!

ADDED:

My code is currently like this:

```
import argparse

def a(args):
    print(f'a({args})')

def b(args):
    print(f'b({args})')

def main():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.set_defaults(func=a) # default command

    sp = parser.add_subparsers()

    pa = sp.add_parser('a')         # subcommand
    pa.set_defaults(func=a)
    pa.add_argument('-p')
    pa.add_argument('-q')

    pb = sp.add_parser('b')         # subcommand
    pb.set_defaults(func=b)
    pb.add_argument('-p')
    pb.add_argument('-x')

    args = parser.parse_args()      # https://docs.python.org/ja/3/library/argparse.html#sub-commands
    args.func(args)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Since -p and -q are options of command a, the default parser does not recognize them.  If I add parser.add_argument('-p') it seems working.  However, if I specify -p for both main and sub parsers by `python m.py -p 1 a -p 2`, it is **allowed** and the latter has precedence.  This is error-prone and I'd like to raise some exception for confliction.  Also, **if I add `required=True`**, both parsers require it, the parser requires the confliction, which I'd like to avoid.

Comment: Have you tried creating an ArgumentParser with two subparsers? The documentation you linked has a very nice example of exactly that. It also shows how to add arguments to the main parser and the subparsers. Try that and then post your code here.

Comment: Okay, I missed the part about a default command. argparse doesn't let you set a default subparser, so that would require some tricks.

Comment: You could use a `set_defaults` in the main parser to set the `func` attribute.  The main could also have a '-a' argument.  Then define 'foo' and 'bar' as usual.  I think the overall behavior will be what you expect (but haven't tested it).